# Nautilus hangs up on mounted shares after suspend

Tags: mount, vpn, shared-folders, umount

After establishing a VPN tunnel to my university, I connect to a Network Share via Shell script like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=xyz,password=abc //10.x.x.x/xyz /media/my_share/
```

It works fine but when I suspend my laptop and later start it up again, the shares won't work anymore. Nautilus hangs up when I click on them.

The VPN connection always disconnects when suspending so I reconnect when starting up again. Maybe it has something to do with that?

has anybody experienced similar issues and can give me some advice? Maybe there is some way to automatically umount all network-shares when suspending? I saw this post [here](https://ccollins.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/automatically-unmount-network-shares-on-ubuntu/)
about umounting when shuting down (anyhow it seems also not to work for me).

Any advice would be helofull!
Best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are hook-scripts in the folder `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/`. Just add another script called for example `99custom` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
#My custom script

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)
                #umount shares
                ;;
        thaw|resume)
                #mount shares
                ;;
        *) exit
                ;;
esac
```

I would split up in two script because you have to cleanly umount the share **before** networking is away, and after that resuming it **after** networking is back.

**Edit:**
If you just want that all cifs shares where unmounted before suspending make a script called `00custom` in the directory `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` with content:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
        hibernate|suspend)
                /bin/umount -t cifs -a
                ;;
        *) exit
                ;;
esac
```

Make sure that the script is executable:

```
chmod 755 00custom
```

After resuming from suspend, your cifs shares should be unmounted.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I dind't quite understand how to split this script up (I#m very new to Ubuntu).Can you explain? And another thing is that I'm not quite sure if this is what I need because probably it won't work to mount the shares again if I loose the VPN connection when suspending...?

Comment: The share do only work when you are connected via vpn, so yes the thaw|resume part is not needed. You just want to umount the drives when suspending, right?

Comment: I tried as suggested leaving the thaw resume part away but instead of suspending the notebook it just brings me to the lockscreen right now. Removing my custom file reestablished the suspend function...any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: after your edit it worked for me!. I also found out that I don't need to umount all the shares necessarily. After waiting around 10 minutes after resume they start to respond again. So it's just a matter of patience. Still if you don't have time for that your solution works smoothly. Thank you!!